# How to Redirect output of cmd command "adb logcat" in Visual Studio(in cmd it never stops unless u press Ctrl+ PauseBreak)?

Tags: adb, logcat

I am using Visual Studio to generate the adb logcat through command prompt and put it into a text box. The thing is that the output of the logcat keeps generating due to which the program gets stuck.

This is my Start logging button code.

```
Dim procForLog As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
Dim prForLog As Process
procForLog.CreateNoWindow = True
procForLog.UseShellExecute = False
procForLog.RedirectStandardInput = True
procForLog.RedirectStandardOutput = True
prForLog = Process.Start(procForLog)
prForLog.StandardInput.WriteLine("adb logcat")
prForLog.StandardInput.Close()
While log = True
    Dim logLineReader As String = prForLog.StandardOutput.ReadLine()
    TextBox1.Text += logLineReader + vbNewLine
End While
prForLog.StandardOutput.Close()
```

'log' is a public boolean variable. I control 'log' value through another button called "stop logging button".

This is my stop logging button code

```
log = false
```

How to I output a log that never ends unless you tel it to?

Like if I type the same command in command prompt "adb logcat" it keeps generating output until I press Ctrl+PauseBreak.

Comment: use `-d` flag to dump current buffers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
prForLog.StandardInput.WriteLine("adb logcat")
```

To

```
prForLog.StandardInput.WriteLine("adb logcat -d")
```

Comment: Thanks @Jared Rummler. That worked. Now I'm getting another problem. My method of Starting the log and stopping it isn't working. Do you know why? Do you know any other method?